# FFMPEG, how to name the output file at my convenience?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ffmpeg, video-processing

I have here a script that allows me to compress all **.mp4** files of a folder.

The output file is:

> original_name.mp4.webm

I would like the output file to be `original_name.webm`.

How to get rid of  **.mp4**?

I think I have to learn `.gsub(/ /, '\ ')`.

Please suggest.

Comment: And the code sorry                Dir.glob("*.mp4") do |my_text_file|
                    puts ' --> converting: ' + my_text_file
                    puts "ffmpeg -i #{my_text_file.gsub(/ /, '\ ')} -b:v 640k  #{my_text_file.gsub(/ /, '\ ')}.webm"
                         `ffmpeg -i #{my_text_file.gsub(/ /, '\ ')} -b:v 640k  #{my_text_file.gsub(/ /, '\ ')}.webm`
                  end

Answer (score 0):

I found it sorry for the buzz, here is the final code that removes ".mp4" and rename it ".webm"

```
Dir.glob("*.mp4") do |my_text_file|
  puts ' --> converting: ' + my_text_file
  puts "ffmpeg -i #{my_text_file.gsub(/ /, '\ ')} -b:v 640k  #{my_text_file.gsub(/.mp4/, '')}.webm"
 `ffmpeg -i #{my_text_file.gsub(/ /, '\ ')} -b:v 640k  #{my_text_file.gsub(/.mp4/, '')}.webm`
end
```

Comment: My problem was I never used gsub but now I will prefer it to the function split.